# How to get the indexvalue of a column with a relation set in QSqlRelationalTableModel?

Tags: foreign-key-relationship, pyqt5, qtsql

In  `QsqlRelationalTableModel` foreign keys are resolved to human readable strings, if a relation for the column containing a foreign key is set. In my application stationids are resolved to stationnames.

For some purposes i need the stationid too. `QsqlRelationalTableModel.data()` or `QsqlRelationalTableModel.itemData()` only return the displayValue (for displayrole as well as for editrole). How can i get the corresponding foreign key (indexValue)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> QsqlRelationalTableModel.relationModel() returns a QSqlTableModel object for accessing the table for which column is a foreign key.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlrelationaltablemodel.html#relationModel

By the `setFilter()` method of `relationModel()` the corresponding  id (indexValue) can be found, if the displayValue is unique:

```
rm = self.relationModel(<index column>)
f = '<columnname> = "{}"'.format(<displayvalue>)
rm.setFilter(f)
id = rm.data(rm.index(0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean you can change qsqlrelationaltablemodel.cpp file like this:

```
QString QSqlRelationalTableModel::selectStatement() const
......
            //!!! my
            fList.append(QLatin1String(", "));
            fList.append(relTableAlias);
            fList.append(QLatin1String("."));
            fList.append(relation.indexColumn());
            fList.append(QLatin1String(" as "));
            fList.append(relation.tableName());
            fList.append(QLatin1String("_"));
            fList.append(relation.indexColumn());
```

I'v tested it on Qt 4.8.1.

Second variant to get you wish right result is to create own class inherited by QSqlTableModel that make as you need.

First you have to reimplemented selectStatement function and create your own behavier.

Here is a beta version of QSqlRelationalTableModelMod1 class for example:
https://kkmspb.ru/development/Qt/database-sql/Extended-Qt/QSqlRelationalTabelModelMod1/

Unfortunetly by russian only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).